# Can I obtain the content rect of a NSTabViewItem witihin its tab bar?

Tags: macos, cocoa

Is there a way to get the content rect of a `NSTabViewItem` in the bar of a `NSTabView`?

The `view` property is just the view to be displayed, when the item is active.

The `tabView` property gives me the tab view but its frame is the entire area used by the tab view (including the currently displayed content view).

I would like to align a `NSPopover` exactly below a specific `NSTabViewItem` but therefor I require the content rect of it.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly. There is no typical API to get the frame of the actual tab control's segments. You can roughly do it if you swap your tab view's switch for an NSSegmentedControl by estimating the frame using the width of each segment, but there's still no explicit way to get the actual frame of a given segment (until the moment that segment is drawn by the NSSegmentedCell).

However, you can get a rect for the segment in a tab view by using the Accessibility APIs. That's a really obtuse way of doing it, but it's possible.

NSTabViewItem doesn't conform to NSAccessibility for some reason, but you can use the older deprecated APIs:

```
[tabViewItem accessibilityAttributeValue:NSAccessibilityPositionAttribute];
[tabViewItem accessibilityAttributeValue:NSAccessibilitySizeAttribute];
```

These give you coordinates in *screen* space, so then you need to convert those to the window (convertRectFromScreen) and the tab view's own frame (convertRect:fromView:). Tedious but doable.